# How to update ionic-native to vers 3x?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

I'm trying to update ionic-native to a version 3.4.3

But it doesn't work. It has updated to version 2.9.0, which is the last 2.x version.

How can I update more?

If i change the version in package.json to 3.4.3, it says:

```
npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: ionic-native@3.4.3
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget 2.9.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.0, 2.7.0, 2.6.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.0, 2.3.2, 2.3.1, 2.3.0, 2.2.17, 2.2.16, 2.2.15, 2.2.14, 2.2.13, 2.2.12, 2.2.11, 2.2.10, 2.2.9, 2.2.8, 2.2.7, 2.2.6, 2.2.5, 2.2.4, 2.2.3, 2.2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.0, 2.1.9, 2.1.8, 2.1.7, 2.1.6, 2.1.5, 2.1.4, 2.1.3, 2.1.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.0, 1.3.27, 1.3.26, 1.3.25, 1.3.24, 1.3.23, 1.3.22, 1.3.21, 1.3.20, 1.3.19, 1.3.18, 1.3.17, 1.3.16, 1.3.15, 1.3.14, 1.3.13, 1.3.12, 1.3.11, 1.3.10, 1.3.9, 1.3.8, 1.3.7, 1.3.6, 1.3.5, 1.3.4, 1.3.3, 1.3.2, 1.3.1, 1.3.0, 1.2.4, 1.2.3, 1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.12, 1.0.11, 1.0.10, 1.0.9, 1.0.8, 1.0.7
```

Do you know why?

My ionic version:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.2.3
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13
```

Thanks

EDIT:

package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.4.3",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.4.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.3.0",
    "ionic-native": "3.4.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "midata": "git+https://github.com/i4mi/midata.js.git#v1.4",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.4.4",
    "pouchdb": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs": "5.2.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.5"
  },
```

EDIT2:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.1.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.3.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^1.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.2.2"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard@~2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-console@1.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device@1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen@~4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation",
    "cordova-plugin-camera",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage@~2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file",
    "cordova-plugin-secure-storage"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
  "description": "OnkoApp2: An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: Does angular 4 work with ionic 2?

Comment: Not yet.But coming weeks they'll release Ionic3 with Angular4 @suraj

Comment: try  `ionic state reset` it will automatically uninstall the plugin and install into new version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

You have to update all the native packages to latest like below.

```
  "@ionic-native/core": "3.4.3",
  "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.3",
  "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.3",
```

After that: `npm i`

**Old Answer**

You just need to do this on your `package.json` file.

Replace old one (`"ionic-native": "2.2.11"`) with this `"@ionic-native/core": "3.1.0",`

after that run `npm i`

**Note:** You must use  `"@angular/core": "2.4.8"` with your `Ionic2` app.No `Angular4` support yet.

Your `package.json` file should be like this.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.1.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.3.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
```

},

Comment: Thanks, I have this problem more:  UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.4.8 and I wanted to use version 3.4.3 of ionic-native, but if I change 3.1.0 to 3.4.3 in ionic-native/core give an error

Comment: just create a new project using:`ionic start myfirstapp blank --v2`.That is it.Why you cannot do that?

Comment: mmh, why to create a new one? Now it's a big project, we cannot simply begin from new now... And I have tried with a new project, just for test, and I have the same error

Comment: OK, then why you include these things to your project? ` "@angular/core": "^4.0.1",`.Those are angular 4 things which are not compatible with ionic2.

Comment: I have changed that following your recommendations. I have added that today, trying to do working the se ionic native 3

Comment: I just told this no? `@ionic-native/core": "3.1.0"` and run `npm i`.That should update only the `native 3.x` thing. I also did the same thing for my project a few days back and no problem at all.I have done that for using native `InAppbrowser` plugin.It is working fine.How it added `Angular 4` modules?

Comment: This is the official doc about it.https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json#L22

Comment: Why remaining focused on this angular 4? I have tell you that was an error and I have changed this following your recommendations... Advancing to 3.1.0 is working following your recommendation, but if you see here https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md it has 3.4.3 version. I need this version to use the keys() method of plugin secure-storage

Comment: OK, then you have to update your latest `package.json` on your post.Put it as a separate one.I would like to see that.

Comment: I added the file to my first post

Comment: please see the **Update** section on my post above.